# How to import MySQL RAW Database files without connection error

Tags: mysql, import, export, dump, server

unfortunately I did not create a 'dump' file with the backup (Data Export) process on MySQL Workbench 8.0.26.

When I copy the old database files to the new Data directory, the server fails to start with the message:

```
Could not connect to MySQL: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061) (code 2003)
```

Tried to do a clean install of MySQL Server 8.0.26 and Workbench 8.0.26 on Windows Web Server 2008 R2. Which after that install the MySQL Server works fine. But then when I stop the server and copy the old Database files into the new Data directory, the MySQL Server fails to start after that. Although I have read that this is not the usual way to 'backup' and restore a MySQL Database, though I wasn't aware of that before.

Is there any way to convert the old database files into a 'dump' file outside of MySQL Workbench? Or is there some way to import the old MySQL database files into the new database without the MySQL Server failing to startup again?

Thank you.

Comment: Look the error messages in the error log. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-logs.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way to convert tablespace files to dump files if MySQL Server cannot read them.

Some tablespaces can be imported if they were exported properly, but yours probably were not exported.

Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-table-import.html for details. If you had not prepared your tables with `FLUSH TABLES .. FOR EXPORT`, then you cannot import them.

Comment: Greetings Bill, thank you for the answer. Surprisingly I was able to get my database back up and running from one of my RAW data file backup folders. I'll definitely use the 'dump' backup process from now on. (of course after all of my Osgrid regions and Halcyon world are shut down.) Thank you, Shalom.